# Rendering Sub Component from custom shared module Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, jhipster

I'm new to angular and I have trouble trying to display a component inside another component.

The schema:
I have a navbar that makes the router outlet navigate to "component1" using routing.
Then inside component 1 I have `<component-2>` tag which stays as it is.
If I navigate to component-2 using routing it renders properly.

main.component.html

```
<div class="flex">
    <div>
            <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
            <div class="container-fluid col-10 offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card jh-card shadow">
                            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                            <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
                        </div>
                        <jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component1.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ClientSharedModule } from '../shared';
import { COMPONENT1_ROUTE, Component1 } from './';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ClientSharedModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([ COMPONENT1_ROUTE ], { useHash: true }),
    ],
    declarations: [
      Component1
    ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class Component1Module {}
```

component1.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class=""> searchBar</div>
        <div> some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
<component-2>test</component-2>
```

component-2.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-2',
  templateUrl: './component-2.component.html',
  styles: [
      'component-2.scss'
  ]
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
      console.log('COMPONENT CONSTRUCTED');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('COMPONENT INITIALISED');
  }

}
```

custom-shared.module.ts

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
    
    Component2Module
} from './component-2/component-2.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Component2Module,
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  exports: [
    Component2Module
  ],

  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class CustomSharedModule { }
```

component-2.module.ts

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ClientSharedModule} from '../../shared';
import {
    Component2Details,
    Component2,
    component2Route
} from './';

const ENTITY_STATE = [
    component2Route,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ClientSharedModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATE)
  ],
  declarations: [
      Component2,
      Component2Details
  ],
  entryComponents: [
      Component2,
      Component2Details
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class Component2Module {
    constructor() {}
}
```

I replaced real name of component.
As it is I have no error at compile time nor execution time.
I believe it's scope related or  injection related, but I can't find the solution.
If someone can give me some help it will be much appreciated.

Additional info : Jhipster v 4.14.2
Monolithic app. Angular 5+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems resolved, My mistake was to think that if i export component2 in compent2-module and then import this module in my shared module, component would be available where ever I import my shared module.

The solution is to export/declare component2 directly from the shared module.
Then it is available where ever I import my shared module.

Hope this could help some people.
See ya